# How to convert multiple cell selection to single cell selection using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

In myscenario, I am trying to create single cell selection `checkmark` at a time.  I used below code for multiple cell selection with `isSelected` Bool value for selection cell persistent. Now, how to convert below code for single cell `selection`.

**My Code Below**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    let item = self.titleData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        titleData[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        let selectedTitle = titleData.filter{$0.isSelected}
        print("\(selectedTitle)")
    }
```

Comment: show the code where  you modified `isSelected` state

Comment: If you want to switch between single and multiple selection. you can do logic for  tap 3 seconds to enable multiple selection and tap to select single selection.

Answer (score 2):

First, in viewDidLoad(), make your tableView to allow single selection only. like this:

```
yourTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

then you can use `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` for this. This will enable only one selection at a time.

```
// assign isSelected true and accessoryType to checkmark

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    self.titleData[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
    let selectedTitle = self.titleData[indexPath.row].title
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

}

// assign isSelected false and accessoryType to none

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    self.titleData[indexPath.row].isSelected = false
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik and thats what my above code will do.

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com I have updated my question. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com I tried your code but don't know how to migrate with mycode.  Above I have update my question. Can you please reupdate your answer once again.

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com what about `let selectedTitle = titleData.filter{$0.isSelected}
        print("\(selectedTitle)")` this line. I am storing selected values into array.

Comment: why are you storing it in array if you only want single selection only. you can directly store it in a String variable right?. Updated the code. check didSelectRow

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com I am sorry. Your right. I will check it now and update you here

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com but I can't able to provide this `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` for making cell highlight blink.

Comment: other than that blink, is everything else working? add,         `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`
in `didSelect` as well as `didDeselect` if you want both of them to blink.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain global variable because if you want to manage using your array you need to reset isSelected bit of array every time before you do selection.

```
var isSelected = false
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let item = self.titleData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
        cell.accessoryType = isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
     }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         isSelected = true
        tableView.reloadData()

     }
```

Comment: thats just copy paste of previous answer

Comment: checkout difference without deselection how deselect will get called for that you have to click on selected cell again. In my case you don't have to deselect on simply select any other cell and already selected cell's selection will get updated.

Comment: If single selection is enabled, then deSelect gets called automatically when other cell is selected.

Comment: also, tableView.reloadData() is a bad practice just for reloading one row.